# How to insert a checkbox before an element by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have generated a table with JQuery csv2table plugin. How could I insert checkboxes in every table box?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the plugin, but in general `.append()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/append/)</sup> and `.appendTo()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)</sup> should help you out here.

```
$('<input>', {
    type:  'checkbox'
}).appendTo(/* "#tableid" or "#tableid td" or "#tableid .tablebox" */ );
```

**Update**
In referrence to your comment. You can use jQuerys `:nth-child`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)</sup> selector to have a query like I believe you want. For instance

```
.appendTo($('#table').find('tr:nth-child(3n)').find('td:nth-child(8n)'));
```

Comment: Thanks jAndy! One more question here. If I just want to add checkbox to some of the table box, such as 3<col<8, how could I do that? I guess I have to append them to specific elements. Does that mean I have to gave each table box an id?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also use the [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) method:

**Example:**

```
$('<input type="checkbox" name="namehere" />').insertBefore('selector');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a unique `id` for each checkbox you can [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the input using the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method in order to use the index for the `id`:

```
$('#yourTable').find('td').each(function(i,obj){
  $(obj).append('<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox'+i+'" name="checkbox'+i+'">');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var counter=1;
    var chk="<input type='checkbox' id='chk_'"+counter+"'/>";

    $("table#t tr td").each(function(){
        $(this).append(chk);
        counter++;
    });
});
```

try [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/fth6x/)